# Bootstrap navbar mobile-toggle isn't working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When I shrink the browser the mobile-toggle is visible, but when I click on it, it doesn't expand. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-right nav-pills">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#portfolio">1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu " id="prtf">
                            <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you should be loading your javscript in the <head>

Comment: @godmode But not in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)..

Comment: well it should at least be before your navbar right?

Comment: @5ervant, it's interesting though, if you go to a template and inspect the page they import their js files in the <head> http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

Comment: @5ervant It is good practice to load js dependencies on the head section unless they cause loading issues for the page

Comment: According to bootstrap  it's not.

Comment: @godmode Did you see the `<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->` in the source?

Comment: Thanks for the tip , but I've previously tested it in the head with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy pasted your navbar section to jsfiddle and it seems to be working as it should. I think it could be that your js file path is not correct.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/LrLffj2m/1/

Please replace this line:

`<script src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

With this:

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was the solution!

Comment: Glad I could help Eddi :) Also, do consider moving js links to your head section as it is, as mentioned proper coding practice.

Comment: I usually have it in the head area, but not with bootstrap. The page is faster when I integrate the JS files at the end. But thanks again!